# How do I prevent the contenteditable tag from being inherited in child elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `<div contenteditable>` with a `<span>` inside of it. The text inside of the `<div>` I want to be editable, but the `<span>` I do not want users to be able to edit.

Sample:

```css
#editable {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable>
  Sample text including a <span>FANCY TAG</span> in the middle.
</div>
```

The desired end result is a box where users can type in what they'd like, but have styled tags inline that are not editable. Since you cannot put `<span>` tags inside of `<input type="text">` or `<textarea>` blocks, I'm left with using `<div contenteditable>`.

How do I make all the text inside the `<div>` editable *except for* the `<span>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `contenteditable="false"` to your `span tag` thus this prevents user from editing your `span tag.`

```css
#editable {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable>
  Sample text including a <span contenteditable="false">FANCY TAG</span> in the middle.
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that would be my suggestion - However, because the span is within a contenteditable div, this doesn't prevent the span from being deleted in my experience with the delete or backspace keys.

Comment: @TonyDuffill yes that's true, but it disables the content editing for span tag as you asked. And it can be achieved if we change the span position and adjust text.

Comment: Works great! The ability to delete them is an added bonus, that I'd like to keep.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the same question I had and the answer I was hoping to find. I'm working on letting power users generate their own custom e-mail body for custom notifications and they can drop in "tags" which are essentially variables that will be replaced with values when the e-mail is sent out.